# Present Perfect vs Present Perfect Continuous with the verb "find"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Which version of these two sentences is correct?

- He **has been finding** it difficult to adjust to his new school.
- He **has found** it difficult to adjust to his new school.

Answer (score 2):

Substantively, they mean the same thing. They **may** have **slightly** different connotations. For example, I might say

> He has been having difficulties adjusting, but he is trying very hard to do so

but

> He has had difficulties adjusting, but he seems to be doing better in the past week.

Using the continuous form stresses to me that past and present are much the same whereas the present perfect does not necessarily give the same stress. I am not sure that most educated native speakers would recognize that distinction so it may be a personal quirk.

Comment: @Jeff.Morrow.Why  have you not  used  the  original  sentences.Can  find  be  used in the  progressive  forms?

Comment: @Fumble Fingers .I would like to know whether ** Find**  can  be used  in the  progressive  forms

Comment: @Jasson Bassford.Can find  be used in the progressive  forms?

Comment: @JVL Of course "find" can be used in a progressive tense. "I was finding my way in the dark when I stumbled over the cat and stubbed my toe."